# JQuery .each processing before Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each, synchronous

I have a Javascript (Jquery) function that iterates over input elements in a form, assembles an array to JSON stringily, and then posts it to an AJAX endpoint. The each is running after the AJAX call, and I am not sure what the most accepted method is for calling the AJAX endpoint after the each.

My function:

```
function FormHandler() {
    var data = [];
    $("form#myForm :input").each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var field_key = input[0]['name'].substr(4);
        var value = input[0]['value'];
        data[field_key] = value;
        console.log(data);
    });
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'https://myendpoint.xxx/v1/' + pathname,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'data': JSON.stringify(data)},
        success: function (thisdata) {
            console.log(thisdata);
        }
    });
};
```

Calling this AJAX sends an empty data array in JSON, but the console logs in the foreach show the data element growing by the next input value at each turn. I have tried placing the AJAX call in a function after the each's first function, but that doesn't work.

Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: have you tried adding a trace before the start of the iteration and after it. The only asynchronous part of the code you posted is the ajax execution.

Comment: you can use formdata object or serialize or SeriallizeArray , and just send it in post, without stringify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `var data = []` to `var data = {}`.
In the each-loop you're adding properties to an array, which `JSON.stringify` does not pick up on.